# bash:自分自身の標準エラーを参照する方法

Tags: bash

プロセスが自分自身の標準エラーに出力した内容を、あとから参照する方法を探しています。

背景です。
コマンドmycmdとmycheckとmysendmailがあります。
コマンド"mycmd"は、コマンド"mycheck"を実行して、エラーになればmysendmailを実行します。
"mysendmail"は標準入力の内容を本文にして、管理者にメールを送信します。
"mycheck"の出力するエラーログは、"mycmd"の呼び出し元の標準エラーと、メール本文の両方に出力する必要があります。

現在はプロセス置換を使って以下のように書いています。

コマンド"mycmd" :

```sh
mycheck 2> >(tee err.log >&2)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  mysendmail < err.log
  exit -1
fi
```

これで動作は問題ないのですが、一時ファイル"err.log"が作成されるのが、
いまいちスマートでないと思っています。
一時ファイルを作成せずに仕様を満たすやり方はあるでしょうか。

できれば自分自身の標準エラーを参照する手段を使って（例えば仮想ファイル "STDERR_CACHE" に標準エラーの内容が記録される、など）、以下のようにかくことが理想なのですが、そのような手段はあるでしょうか。

```sh
mycheck || {
  mysendmail < $STDERR_CACHE
  exit -1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

シェル変数(`STDERR_CACHE`)に格納する方法はどうでしょうか。`mysendmail` への入力には bash の `here string(<<<)` を使います。

```
#!/bin/bash
        :

STDERR_CACHE="$(mycheck 2>&1 >/dev/null)"
exit_status=$?
echo "${STDERR_CACHE}" >&2

if [ ${exit_status} -ne 0 ]; then
  mysendmail <<< "${STDERR_CACHE}"
  exit -1
fi
```